# Why are arrow functions as static members values not lexically scoped?

Tags: javascript, static, es6-class, ecmascript-next, class-fields

```js
class Foo {
  static v = 123;

  static bar = () => this.v;
}

console.log(Foo.bar());
```

I expect this code to return `undefined`, because arrow functions are lexically scoped, hence `this` must be eagerly bound to the outer scope.

Yet, it returns `123`.

Why exactly does this happen?

And yep, I understand it's still stage 3, but still - why does the proposed standard behave like that? (See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties for another example.)

Comment: https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#runtime-semantics-class-definition-evaluation 10.a "Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to classScope." so

Comment: @YuryTarabanko please post as an answer

Comment: It looks like every "field" is actually wrapped into yet a function/method: https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#runtime-semantics-class-field-definition-evaluation, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @FelixKling it looks convincing but their `FunctionCreate(Method, formalParameterList, Initializer, lex, true, privateScope).` has `PrivateScope` and `Strict` swapped.

Comment: Apparently those methods are then executed to create the actual properties in `DefineField`: https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#sec-define-field (step 5.a)

Comment: @FelixKling yep, I altered my comment - they confused the order of 2 last arguments. From your link it is `FunctionCreate(Method, formalParameterList, Initializer, lex, true, privateScope)` but should be `FunctionCreate(Method, formalParameterList, Initializer, lex, privateScope, true)`

Comment: @zerkms: Maybe just a typo?

Comment: Definitely a typo, sorry for shifting focus to this irrelevant thing. Otherwise as I just mentioned, your guess looks very convincing to me :-)

Comment: Somehow `DefineField` doesn't seem to be used for static fields though? Need to do more digging...

Comment: Ah, wrong spec. https://tc39.es/proposal-static-class-features/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-classelementevaluation -> 34.a ... not easy to follow when the relevant sections are spread over multiple specs ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr: Every class field (static or not) is internally wrapped in a method which gets invoked with the corresponding receiver (class or instance) at some point.

---

So, I'm not sure on some of those details *, but basically this happens:

For every field with an initializer (static or not), a function/method is created, with the initializer as its body. So this

```
static foo = () => this.v;
```

becomes *something* like this internally

```
function () { () => this.v }
```

That's in [the proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-static-class-features/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-classelementevaluation) in step 28, which eventually leads to [`ClassFieldDefinitionEvaluation` in this spec](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#runtime-semantics-class-field-definition-evaluation). The method is created in step 3.e.

The static fields (which are methods now) are then taken and called with the class object itself as *receiver* (i.e. the `this` value inside that intermediate method is set to the class object). This happens in step 34.a, which leads to [`DefineField` in this spec](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#sec-define-field). Finally the return value (in your case the arrow function) is used as value for the actual property.

Expressed as code, this is roughly what happens:

```
class Foo {}

Foo.v = function() { return 123; }.call(Foo);
Foo.bar = function() { return () => this.v; }.call(Foo);
```

---

*: I'm not quite clear how the intermediate method *returns* the value, but there is probably something that says that the last expression of the function body is returned or something.

Comment: I have a feeling that this part of the proposal [is not quite final](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/issues/38). The function wrapping looks like a hack to me, I'd hope they polish this up before stage 4.